# How to bind javascript array with @RequestParam using FormData?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, form-data

The problem is binding javascript arraylist with RequestParam annotation.
I have a form data like this works fine if there is no nokDataList.
nokInfoDatas is an javascript array that in console it looks:
[image]

```
var requestData = JSON.stringify(nokInfoDatas);
    console.log("nokInfoDatas");
    console.log(nokInfoDatas);
    console.log("requestData");
    console.log(requestData);
var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('photo', file);
        fd.append('testId', testId);
        fd.append('nokDataList', nokInfoDatas);
var ajaxData = {
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            url: sendUrl,
            headers: headersData,
    };
```

Backend side:

```
public @ResponseBody String answer(HttpServletRequest request, 
            @RequestParam(value = "photo") MultipartFile photo,
            @RequestParam(value = "testId") String testId,
        @RequestParam(value = "nokDataList") List<NokDataDTO> nokInfoDtos
            )
```

Comment: can you post the entity class ? (NokDataDTO)

Comment: @harshil it is a basic java class that has :
private Long id;
private String nokInfo;
private String nokData;

Comment: does it have setters ?

Comment: @harshil yes both have setters and getters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as follows :

Create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with your JSON data (requestData) :

```
var requestData = JSON.stringify(nokInfoDatas);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('photo', file);
fd.append('testId', testId);
fd.append('nokDataList', new Blob([requestData], {
  type: "application/json"
}));
```

Change @RequestParam to [@RequestPart](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html) for parsing JSON with multi-part.

```
public @ResponseBody String answer(HttpServletRequest request, 
       @RequestParam(value = "photo") MultipartFile photo,
       @RequestParam(value = "testId") String testId,
       @RequestPart(value = "nokDataList") List<NokDataDTO> nokInfoDtos
      )
```

Comment: Did not work for me, same problem about binding. By the way I did not use any kind of type like json because when I use to pass file,it blows.Maybe that is why your way didnt work?

Comment: @DogaOzdemir I tried the code and work properly. Maybe you need also Spring multi-part configuration. You can check my configuration [here](https://gist.github.com/gurkan0791/feb8c5bf85ce8ea4f9fd77c6ebef886c). I'm using Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE.

Comment: after deleting file append,binding worked fine! But there is a weird thing that  List<NokDataDTO> nokInfoDtos inside LinkedHashMap values

Comment: @DogaOzdemir try removing headers:headersData your ajax method. I tried without it.

Comment: Solved whit this :
List<NokDataDTO> nList= mapper.convertValue(nokInfoDtos, new TypeReference<List<NokDataDTO>>() { });

thanks for help anyway!